# Firebase functions does middleware increase requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I basically have a very quick and simple question.
I have a protected cloud https functions where I need to verify users first.
Is using a middleware possible to prevent the amount of successful calls increasing if the middleware returns 403 status?

Because otherwise people could spam my endpoint and my bill will keep increasing over-time.

Comment: I'm unclear how any middleware would be an improvement. Seems like you'd still have to pay for the spam invocations of your middleware.  Maybe you can edit the question to be more specific about why you think this strategy would be more cost effective.

Comment: Its not a strategy right now, it's more of an open question on what strategy would work against spam on a public API route which requires an API key from the users